# Prolog: How do I check whether item exists in the database before adding?

Tags: prolog

I start out with a blank database. I need to add some database entries to it, for example:

```
person(John,male)
person(Veronica,female)
person(Jessica,female)
```

I am adding entries like this:

```
add_person(N,G):-asserta(person(N,G)).
```

Howerver, I do not want to add the same person twice, so I need to check before adding.

I am trying to do it this way:

```
add_person(N,G):- \+ person(N,G),asserta(person(N,G)).
```

The problem is that I cannot query the database with, say `person(John,male)` if my database is blank. So `person(N,G)` fails with existence error, and I cannot add at all.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which variant of Prolog you're using, but you can declare some predicates to be dynamic, by putting this line at the top of your code:

```
:- dynamic person/2.
```

This is described in the [SWI-Prolog documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(dynamic)/1).

Comment: I'm using GNU Prolog, so the correct syntax for the command was `:-dynamic(person/2).` Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The way you write `John` is a variable and not an atom. You should use only lowercase for atoms (`john`, `veronica`, etc.). I just tried your code and it works fine:

```
person(john, male).

add_person(N,G):-
    \+ person(N,G),
    asserta(person(N,G)).
```

Adding `john` again fails and returns `false`.

Comment: Yes, it does work; I just had to figure out how not to run into an existence exception when the db didn't have any data in it. Using dynamic predicates worked!